# Blank screen before Windows login screen - is my SSD about to die?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, hard-drive-failure

I'm running a Windows 7 system with an [ASRock H61M-HVS motherboard](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H61M-HVS/index.asp) which boots from a [128GB Kingston SV200 SSD](https://ssd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/2473/KINGSTON-SV200S3128G). The drive has been in use in this capacity since 2010, and until recently has had fast boot up times.

For the last few weeks, I've noticed that during boot, a blank screen shows after the Windows boot logo, and persists for between 30 seconds to a minute before the login screen finally appears. The fact that this happens on boot makes me suspect that after almost a decade in use the SSD is finally about to die.

However, what's throwing me off is that CrystalDiskInfo and a `smartctl` long scan show the drive as being healthy, and all the attributes seem to be safely above their thresholds:

[image]

Obviously I have backups, but if I need to spend the money to buy a new SSD, I'd rather know sooner than later to avoid any downtime.

Is my SSD about to die, or is there another likely cause for the long blank screen?

Comment: Diagnostics are not infallible, and can overlook imminent failure. If your motherboard supports it, an M.2 drive can be less spendy since it's circuit board+chips only, no metal enclosure. If your motherboard supports NVMe PCIe drives, that's faster still, but more spendy. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @K7AAY The motherboard is an ASRock H61M-HVS, and as far as I can tell it doesn't support M.2 or NVMe - just SATA 2.0 (3.GB/s) and PCIE 2.0 x16. I'm on a low income so if I do have to sink something on a new SSD, I'd probably go up to 256GB, but I'd probably be limited to SATA instead of the PCIE 2.0.

Comment: I really would like a second opinion on this though. If the SSD is failing, then I can buy one in time for Black Friday/Cyber Monday, but if it isn't, I really can't afford to spend the money there if it's not actually needed.

Comment: Wise move. BTW, if the  PCIe x16 bus slot is open in your PC, you can obtain an inexpensive (well, for Yanks, anyway) PCIe bus card https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=PCIe+card+for+M.2+NVMe+drives  which will accept M.2 NVMe SSDs and run at PCIe x4 bus speed. http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2839021/ssd-pci-adapter-worth.html